# sublime text 2 dart build error

Tags: sublimetext2, dart

I have configured sublime text 2 according to this [video](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/02/using-dart-with-sublime-text.html) from Dart site. I have added this `"dartsdk_path": "/home/green/dart/dart-sdk",` to the Preference -> Setting-user.  The syntax highlighting and and line indention works perfectly. But when i try to build i have the following error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'dart2js', u'--minify', u'-o/home/green/Desktop/darttut/untitled.dart.js', u'/home/green/Desktop/darttut/untitled.dart']]
[dir:  /var/www]
[path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/green/bin]
[Finished]
```

Did I miss something? or did i have done something wrong? I am using Ubuntu 13.04 x64 os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your Dart build file (`~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Dart/Dart.sublime-build`) to include the full path to the `dart2js` command - something along the lines of:

```json
"cmd": ["/full/path/to/dart2js", "--minify", "-o$file.js", "$file"],
```

You will also want to either add the path to `dart2js` to your `$PATH` environment variable, or, better yet, make a link to it in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/dart2js /usr/local/bin/dart2js
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did as you said and it worked perfectly. :)